# An old question resurfaces for closing

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, close-reasons

I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1661154/what-is-difference-between-expected-fisher-information-and-observed-fisher-infor) in the close vote queue. I agree it's seems very vague and hard to answer, but apparently the users who know more about statistics disagree since the person who commented on the question seems to understand it, and there's a very complete looking answer, so I went to hit "Keep Open".

But then I noticed the question is from 2016. Why is it resurfacing now, and why close a 4 year old question that already has a (unaccepted) answer? Is it site policy to close abandoned questions if they don't have an accepted answer? If so, why is there not simply an "abandoned" close-vote reason? I mean, what would you do with an abandoned question which is well-written and can't be justified as closable on the usual grounds of lacking context, being off-topic, etc?

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32773/471884 and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19377/why-close-old-questions-with-accepted-answers-using-the-no-context-reason

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Okay, so it wasn't closed for being abandoned, it was just closed for the actual reason selected by the close votes?

Comment: I suspect the original poster could give an interesting account of what motivated the Question, and the importance of that might not have been obvious to them at the time.

Comment: Currently there is a single vote to close on that question and it is mine. Questions at an advanced level also need to add some context and details. The site is not only designed for experts to answer, but also for those who are non-experts but have some desire to learn. Such questions often don't give any incentives to learn anything.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh That's funny. I could have sword the other day it had at least 4 close votes. In fact I think I remember seeing it closed. Was it re-opened?

Comment: Yes it was reopened! You can see timeline

Comment: But I won't engage in some sort of close reopen cycle.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I must not have enough rep to see the timeline.

Comment: I don't know if viewing timeline is a privilege. Your rep does not seem low either. Please click on the clock icon (below voting buttons) on any post to see timeline.